# .NET server garbage collection and object lifetime

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection

Myself and a colleague are having a difference of opinion on when an object can be garbage collected in .NET. Take the following code:

```
Stream stream=getStream();
using(var request=new Request(stream))
{
    Stream copy=request.Stream;

    // From here on can "request" be garbage collected?

    DoStuff1();
    DoStuff2(copy);
}
```

My colleague claims that when a release build is run using the server garbage collector that it is valid for the `request` object to be garbage collected after the call to `request.Stream`. He asserts that this only happens with the server garbage collector, and never with the workstation garbage collector.

The reason this is that the `Request` class had a finalizer that was closing the `Stream` given to the request. As a result, when `DoStuff2` went to use the stream it got an "object disposed" exception. Since the finalizer can only be run by the garbage collector my colleague says that a garbage collection must have taken place before the end of the finally block, but after the last use of `request`

However, it's my belief that since the above code is just shorthand for something like this:

```
Stream stream=getStream();
Request request=null;

try
{
    Stream copy=request.Stream;

    // From here on can "request" be garbage collected?

    DoStuff1();
    DoStuff2(copy);
}
finally
{
    if(request!=null)
        request.Dispose();
}
```

Then `request` cannot be garbage collected after the call to `request.Stream` at it is still reachable from the `finally` block.

Also, if it were possible for the garbage collector to collect the object then the `finally` block would potentially exhibit undefined behavior as `Dispose` would be called on a GC'd object, which doesn't make sense. Likewise, it isn't possible to optimize away the `finally` block as an exception could be thrown within the `try`/`using` block before any garbage collection had taken place, which would require the `finally` block to execute.

Ignoring the issue of closing the stream in the finalizer, is it ever possible for the garbage collector to collect the object before the end of the `finally` block, and in effect optimize away the logic in the `finally` block?

Comment: You are correct, request cannot be GCed until the finally has run.

Comment: Note, that if request.Dispose does not use instance fields request *can* be collected before Dispose is called on it. That's a rare circumstance.

Comment: Advice: Don't use finalizers. Then, this question becomes moot. You cannot detect the GC at work (except through very unusual means such as finalizers or debugging APIs). Why would Request.Finalize need to close the stream? The stream itself has a finalizer.

Comment: @usr - sure. However, our `Dispose` method is doing stuff!

Comment: You both got it wrong, ODE *never* has anything to do with GC.  A collected object cannot throw an exception.  It is always an ownership bug in your code, disposing or closing a stream and continuing to use it anyway.  Such a bug is highly visible in the snippet, the stream returned by getStream() will be disposed after this code finishes running.  Pretty unlikely to be correct.

Comment: @HansPassant - I understand that. My questions is is there ever an scenario or optimization whereby the garbage collector ever GC the `request` object before the end of the `using`/`finally` block? The ODE is caused by a badly coded finalizer in the `Request` object, but my point is it should never run the finalizer until the end of the `using` block and then only after `Dispose`.

Comment: @usr Are you sure?  Since the reference to the object is passed to the `Dispose` method, I'd expect that to be considered a usage of the variable.  I'd expect that the reference could be collected *as soon as `Dispose` is called* (assuming it uses no instance members).  I'm not positive about that though.

Comment: The problem is that the stream is shared between `copy` and `request`. When `copy` falls out of scope at the closing of the using branch, the stream shared between `copy` and `request` is closed and disposed of. When request falls out of scope, it throws when trying to get rid of the stream (as it was already handled when `copy` was taken care of). Visual Studio code analyzer will flag this as multiple dispose of the same resource, and the related material will tell you to null out request before leaving the using block.

Comment: @StarPilot - the stream isn't disposed until someone calls `Dispose` on it. There's only one call to `Stream.Dispose` and that via the badly written finalizer in `Request`. The problem is that it's claimed that `Request` can be GC'd (and hence its finalizer called) before the `using` block exits, which I think is incorrect.

Comment: @Servy I'm quite sure the reference used to call Disposed is a root because it is in a register or stack slot which must be tracked to support relocation. But Dispose could be inlined and disappear. The receiver type is known.

Comment: @usr Right, didn't think about that, so yes, it is something to worry about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's quite a bit going on in this question, so I'll tackle the overarching issues first.

1. The variable declared in a `using` statement will not be garbage collected before the end of the block, for exactly the reason you indicated - a reference is held in order to call `Dispose()` in the implicit `finally` block.
2. If you find yourself writing a finalizer in C#, you are probably doing something wrong. If your finalizer in C# calls `Stream.Dispose()`, you are *definitely* doing something wrong. Outside of an implementation of .NET itself, I have seen hundreds of misused finalizers, and [exactly 1 finalizer](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blame/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/Core/NativeMethods.cs#L37-L40) that was actually needed. For more information, see [DG Update: Dispose, Finalization, and Resource Management](http://joeduffyblog.com/2005/04/08/dg-update-dispose-finalization-and-resource-management/).
3. `ObjectDisposedException` has nothing to do with finalization. This exception generally occurs when code calls `Dispose()` on an object (not finalize), and then a later call is made to do something with the object.

   Sometimes it's not obvious when code is disposing of a `Stream`. One case that surprised me was using [`StreamContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.streamcontent.aspx) as part of sending an HTTP request using `HttpClient`. The implementation calls `Stream.Dispose()` after sending the request, so I had to write a wrapper `Stream` class called [`DelegatingStream`](https://github.com/sharwell/openstack.net/blob/v2-development/src/OpenStack.Net/OpenStack/IO/DelegatingStream.cs) to preserve our library's original behavior during the conversion from `HttpWebRequest` to `HttpClient`.

One scenario where you could see an `ObjectDisposedException` is if the `getStream()` method caches a `Stream` instance and returns it for multiple future calls. If `Request.Dispose()` disposes of the stream, or if `DoStuff2(Stream)` disposes of the stream, then the next time you attempt to use the stream you'll get an `ObjectDisposedException`.

Comment: Definitely TRUE. The Object Disposal is a pattern implement by the Framework to allow an easy wait for object to free resources and is not bound to the GC directly. The only bound is the fact that a Disposed object normally free resources and this resources can be available for deletition. In Stream you need to check the implementation in each case to see what happend.

Answer (score 7):

Per the [language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), section 3.9: "If the object, or any part of it, cannot be accessed by any possible continuation of execution, other than the running of destructors, the object is considered no longer in use, and it becomes eligible for destruction." `using` introduces a `Dispose` call in a `finally` block (section 8.13), which is something other than running a destructor, and must execute except in circumstances when even `finally` blocks don't execute (which the specification doesn't cover, and usually only happens when your entire AppDomain is on its way to the graveyard anyway).

An object in a `using` block isn't eligible for GC. In your example, `request` is not eligible for destruction until after the `using` statement, irrespective of whether it's used in the rest of the block. The only corner case (as mentioned in the comments by others) is when your `Dispose` implementation makes no use of its `this` parameter. In that case, the `Dispose` would not prevent the object from being eligible for destruction -- but if that happens, the question of when it can be collected is moot (as it should be -- garbage collection, when implemented correctly, should have no observable effect on a correctly implemented program).

Comment: I thought the using statement created a weak reference, but don't see anything in the language spec to that effect.  The way to check for sure if the variable can be GC'ed is to call GC.ForceGC *twice*.  The first call will cause the Dispose method to be called.  The 2nd call will cause the object memory to be released

Comment: @KC-NH: There is no `GC.ForceGC` method. You could artificially detect if an object is eligible for destruction by implementing a finalizer, setting an external flag and calling `GC.Collect()` followed by `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`. Obviously this is not something you want to do in production code, so it has teaching value only. If you try this with a variable in a `using`, you will see it cannot be collected until the `using` has finished. In my tests, this is true even if the `Dispose()` accesses no members at all.

Comment: Sorry.  I really meant GC.Collect.  I would test it by having Dispose() log that it was called. If you have a finalizer, log that it was called too.

Comment: @KC-NH: be careful not to confuse `Dispose()` with finalization -- they're entirely unrelated. `Dispose()` is called if and when you call it -- preferably through a `using`. The finalizer (if implemented) is invoked by the finalization thread. If you allocate an object but never call `Dispose()` (and your finalizer doesn't, either) then `Dispose()` simply won't get called -- the runtime doesn't consider it anything special. That said, most implementations that have both do call `Dispose()` from the finalizer.

Comment: You're right. I believe the design pattern is to release the resource in Dispose() and call Dispose() from the finalized. I had forgotten that the GC doesn't recognize IDisposable. This is one of those patterns I lookup every time is need it.